# R- How can I create a heat map where buffers are colored according to associated values?

Tags: r

I have a trajectory characterized by many coordinates. For each coordinate, I have created a buffer with a given radius. This results in the following when plotted:

[image]

The red dots represent the coordinates. There is a number associated with each coordinate (say,a number from 1 to 10). Is there a way to create a heat map of sorts where the buffers are colored according to the number? So, coordinates with larger numbers have buffers that are colored darker than coordinates with lower numbers.

Edit: Below is an example of the data. Lon would be x coordinates, and Lat would be y coordinates. It would be fine if the heat map is created without the buffers, and just solely representing the z value.

```
dates      Lat     Lon dates
1 2013-12-03 13:17:05 -2740802 3274666     2
2 2013-12-03 14:17:00 -2740297 3274437     2
3 2013-12-06 14:08:22 -2743000 3285255     2
4 2013-12-01 08:13:23 -2739121 3277843     1
5 2013-12-01 14:13:38 -2741293 3279086     1
6 2013-12-01 15:13:58 -2741791 3279113     1
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: With example data, this is very possible with the `sf` package and `geom_sf` in the development version of `ggplot2`

Comment: Thank you, I have added some example of my data @CalumYou

Comment: What coordinate system is this in? Those aren't normal latitude/longitude degrees